# How to create a hardhat task that calls an external application

Tags: hardhat

In my hardhat task, I'm going to call an external application like this:

```js
import {extendEnvironment, task} from "hardhat/config";
import {exec} from "child_process";
import { TASK_CHECK } from 'hardhat/builtin-tasks/task-names'

task(TASK_CHECK)
  .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre, runSuper) => {
    console.log("checks contracts")
    exec("pwd"); // or any other external app
  });
```

but running `npx hardhat check` prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with spawn?

```
 const { spawn } = await import("child_process");
    const childProcess = spawn('pwd', {
        stdio: "inherit",
      });
    
      childProcess.once("close", (status) => {
        childProcess.removeAllListeners("error");
  
        if (status === 0) {
        console.log('ok')
        } else {
            console.log('error')
        }

      });
  
      childProcess.once("error", (_status) => {
        childProcess.removeAllListeners("close");
        console.log('error')
      });
```

hope it helps!